Saturated subsheaves of polystable bundles are bundles and polystable
Let $(X,h)$ be a smooth polarized projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $E=F^{\oplus r}$ be a slope polystable bundle, that is $F$ is $\mu_h$-slope stable locally free sheaf.
Now is the following true: Assume $G\hookrightarrow E$ is a nontrivial saturated subsheaf with $\mu_h(G)=\mu_h(E)$ then there is some $s$ with $1\leq s \leq r$ such that $G\cong F^{\oplus s}$.
Here is my idea: by a deep result (Theorem V.8.3) in Kobayashi's book "Differential geometry of complex vector bundles" the bundle $E$ is a Hermite-Einstein bundle and since $G$ is saturated in $E$ as well as $\mu_h(G)=\mu_h(E)$ we find that $G$ is a direct summand of $E$, i.e. $E=G\oplus H$.
Now $E=F^{\oplus r}$ is the Krull-Schmidt decomposition of $E$ into indecomposables. Using the uniqueness of this decomposition shows that we must have $G\cong F^{\oplus s}$ for some $1\leq s\leq r$. Hence $G$ is locally free and polystable itself.
Is this idea correct? If yes: is there an "algebraic" proof of this fact, not using Hermite-Einstein bundles?

I do not know about Hermite-Einstein bundles, but one can give a proof as follows. Consider a nonzero composition $G\to F^{\oplus r}\to F$, denote its kernel by $G'$ and the image by $I_F$ (since $G$ is slope semistable and $F$ is slope stable, we have $\mathrm{rk}\ I_F=\mathrm{rk}\ F$). Also, denote the cokernel of inclusion $G\to F^{\oplus r}$ by $H$. We have a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> 0 @>>> G @>>> G @>>> 0\\
\ @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> F^{\oplus r-1} @>>> F^{\oplus r} @>>> F @>>> 0
\end{CD}  $$
By the snake lemma we obtain an exact sequence
$$0\to G'\to F^{\oplus r-1}\to H'\to 0,$$
where $H'$ is a kernel of a map from a torsion-free sheaf $H$, hence torsion-free. The slope of $G'$ is equal to the slope of $G$, so by induction $G'\cong F^{\oplus t}$ for some $t$. We form a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> F^{\oplus t} @>>> G @>>> I_F @>>> 0\\
\ @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> F^{\oplus r} @>>> F^{\oplus r} @>>> 0 @>>> 0
\end{CD}  $$
Again by the snake lemma
$$0\to I_F\to F^{\oplus r-t}\to H\to 0,$$
so by induction (if $t>0$) $I_F\cong F, H\cong F^{\oplus (r-t-1)}, G\cong F^{\oplus(t+1)}$.
If $t=0$, then $G\cong I_F$ is not saturated, if it is not equal to $F$. Indeed, there is only one morphism from $I_F$ to $F$, up to proportionality. Consider the exact triple
$$0\to I_F\to F\to T\to 0.$$
Since the slope of $I_F$ is equal to the slope of $F$, we get that $T$ is supported on a subscheme of codimension $\ge 2$. Then, considering the long exact sequences of $\mathrm{Ext}$ groups associated to our exact triple, we get $\mathrm{Hom}(I_F,F)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(F,F)\cong\mathbb C$. Here we use the vanishing of $\mathrm{Ext}^1(T,F)=H^0(\mathcal Ext^1(T,F))$, see e.g. answers to this question. So the map $I_F\to F^{\oplus r}$ factors through a map $I_F\to F$, and $H\cong F^{\oplus (r-1)}\oplus T$ is not torsion-free.
